# Temporary role for member Discord JS

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a function for issuing a temporary role but I have no idea how to do it.

I want the "/warn" command to give the member a "RedRole" and disappear after 30 minutes.

My code without time-limit:

```
run: async (client, interaction, config, db) => {
    let user = interaction.member.id
    
    const RedRole = interaction.guild.roles.cache.get("1082652160057163866")//Server-banned role
        
        await user.roles.add(RedRole);
        
        await interaction.reply({
            content: "Member got "RedRole" to 30 minutes. ✅",
            ephemeral: true
        })
    }
},
```

Comment: Naive [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `setTimeout` function. It is probably the easiest solution but has one issue: if you restart your bot after the /warn is issued and before it got removed, it will forget to remove it.

To prevent this, you can use a database but it's more complicated. You can stick to the first option while you learn more about databases.

```js
run: async (client, interaction, config, db) => {
    let user = interaction.member.id
    
    const RedRole = interaction.guild.roles.cache.get("1082652160057163866")//Server-banned role
        
        await user.roles.add(RedRole);

        const time = 30 * 60 * 1000; // 30mins to ms
        setTimeout(() => user.roles.remove(RedRole), time);
        
        await interaction.reply({
            content: "Member got "RedRole" to 30 minutes. ✅",
            ephemeral: true
        })
    }
},
```